# logic issues in form validation ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

how to implement the logic to react.js like I am writing a code to make a form. how to make it work. Should I go with material UI or SToryBook?

Comment: Material UI and Storybook are quite different things. Are you searching for some UI library with form component?

Comment: there are several React form validation libraries you could use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation to name a couple.